# ¿Cual seria la mejor forma de realizar una expresión regular que solo me permita este formato { 0.01; 0.001; 0.0001; 0.00001....}?

Tags: validación

Tengo en un formulario HTML un campo tipo input text, y quiero que el usuario ingrese por este campo cierta información, pero necesito que ese tipo de información que se ingrese sea de este forma:
0.01; 0.001; 0.0001; 0.00001....

La expresión regular debe ser en javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo la **REGEX** que va a permitir colocar 0.0N1 *(N>=0)* :

```
/0.0+1/g
```

- Con esta herramienta vas a poder validar las Expresiones que vayas armando y hacer diferentes pruebas: https://regexr.com/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tu pronta respuesta, ya lo pruebo y te comento.

Comment: Dale Sarah!, espero tu respuesta :)
No olvides votas positivo si te sirvió